# \textfrench causing no chapter numbers in theorem numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems, polyglossia, arabic

I am dealing with a bilingual document using `polyglossia`: Arabic (main) and French (secondary, mostly math only).

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{XB Yas}
```

The

> \textfrench

command helped me to render theorem numbering with the same font used for the math content (i.e. french text).

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textfrench{\arabic{defn}}}
```

The only problem is that, the mention

> [chapter]

in

```
\newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}[chapter]
```

doesn't  do the expected thing (just get ignored) due to that last line:

```
    \renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textfrench{\arabic{defn}}}
```

The result being chapter numbers not included when numbering that "defn" theorem-like environment.

**EDIT:** The whole context

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE]{\footnotesize \bfseries الفضاءات المترية}
\fancyhead[CO]{\footnotesize \bfseries \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textfrench{\thepage}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
    \setmainlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{french}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{XB Yas}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textfrench{\arabic{defn}}}
\newtheorem{remq}{ملاحظة}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theremq}{\textfrench{\arabic{remq}}}
\newtheorem*{demn}{البرهان}
\newtheorem*{consq}{استنتاج}
\newtheorem{propn}{نتيجة}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thepropn}{\textfrench{\arabic{propn}}}
\newtheorem{xmpl}{مثال}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thexmpl}{\textfrench{\arabic{xmpl}}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\textfrench{\arabic{chapter}}}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textfrench{\arabic{enumi}}}

\linespread{1.5}

\title{الفضاءات المترية}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الفصل}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\chapter{مفاهيم أساسية}
\begin{defn}
لتكن
$X$
مجموعة اختيارية غير خالية. نسمي مسافة على
$X$
كل تطبيق
$d$
من
$X\times X$
في
$\mathbb{R}_+$
يحقق الشروط التالية~:
$$
\begin{aligned}
d(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y & \quad .1 \\
\forall (x,y) \in X^2, \; d(x,y)=d(y,x) & \quad .2 \\
\centerdot \quad \forall (x,y,z) \in X^3, \; d(x,z) \leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z) & \quad .3
\end{aligned}$$
\end{defn}
\begin{remq}
العلاقة الواردة في الشرط 3 تسمى المتراجحة المثلثية و~ذلك لكونها تعبيرا معمما على العلاقة بين أضلاع المثلث في الهندسة الأقليدية حيث أن طول الضلع يكون أقل من أو يساوي مجموع طولي الضلعين الآخرين.
\end{remq}
\end{document}
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

It is not just about enforcing Arabic digits over Hindi digits, as some may think.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please put a small example of code we can compile at the bottom please? Helps people answer if they can copy and paste it and run solutions, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` please

Comment: @JamesT Question edited, as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\textfrench{\arabic{<counter>}}` is definitly not the right way. I would define a `\latin` command that chooses the Roman font as set by `fontsetup`.

I changed the Arabic font, because I don't have XB Ras.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE]{\footnotesize \bfseries الفضاءات المترية}
\fancyhead[CO]{\footnotesize \bfseries \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\latin{\thepage}}

\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\latin{\arabic{defn}}}
\newtheorem{remq}{ملاحظة}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theremq}{\latin{\arabic{remq}}}
\newtheorem*{demn}{البرهان}
\newtheorem*{consq}{استنتاج}
\newtheorem{propn}{نتيجة}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thepropn}{\latin{\arabic{propn}}}
\newtheorem{xmpl}{مثال}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thexmpl}{\latin{\arabic{xmpl}}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\latin{\arabic{chapter}}}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\latin{\arabic{enumi}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\latin}{m}{{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont#1}}

\linespread{1.5}

\title{الفضاءات المترية}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الفصل}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\chapter{مفاهيم أساسية}
\begin{defn}
لتكن
$X$
مجموعة اختيارية غير خالية. نسمي مسافة على
$X$
كل تطبيق
$d$
من
$X\times X$
في
$\mathbb{R}_+$
يحقق الشروط التالية~:
\[
\begin{aligned}
d(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y & \quad .1 \\
\forall (x,y) \in X^2, \; d(x,y)=d(y,x) & \quad .2 \\
\centerdot \quad \forall (x,y,z) \in X^3, \; d(x,z) \leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z) & \quad .3
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{defn}
\begin{remq}
العلاقة الواردة في الشرط 3 تسمى المتراجحة المثلثية و~ذلك لكونها تعبيرا معمما على العلاقة بين أضلاع المثلث في الهندسة الأقليدية حيث أن طول الضلع يكون أقل من أو يساوي مجموع طولي الضلعين الآخرين.
\end{remq}

\end{document}
```

The chapter number is set to 10 in order to show that the order of digits is correct.

[image]

Don't use `$$` with LaTeX.

If you want to add the chapter number to the theorem-like environments:

```
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\latin{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{defn}}}
\renewcommand{\theremq}{\latin{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{remq}}}
\renewcommand{\thepropn}{\latin{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{propn}}}
\renewcommand{\thexmpl}{\latin{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{xmpl}}}
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't get the purpose behind me using \textfrench. It is not about enforcing Arabic digits instead of Hindi. It is about having the numbers in Arabic context rendered with the same fonts as the math content, which is, in my case, computer modern. Just compare how the equations and theorems are numbered in the your version then you will get my point.

Comment: @HamzaNouar OK, fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed! Chapter numbers just disappeared!

Comment: @HamzaNouar I see the chapter number in my image.

Comment: I meant the chapter numbers in the theorem-like environments. It should be 10.1, not just 1.

Comment: @HamzaNouar It's exactly like ***you*** defined in your code. You had `\textfrench{\arabic{defn}}` and so on, didn't you?

Comment: @HamzaNouar That mention with the following `\renewcommand` just tells LaTeX to reset the counter at new chapters. If you want 10.1 you should tell it explicitly.

Comment: So how do I finally enforce the [chapter] thing in \newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}[chapter] while still using my/your tip?

Comment: @HamzaNouar See final edit

Comment: Finally! Much Thanks! It worked with \textfrench though!